# injecting a custom named function into the js Function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I am trying to pass a custom function named callpaul() into the scope of the Function constructor so that the function can be called inside the scope of Function. According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function#examples) it seems like this should work, what am I doing wrong?

```js
    let fil={}
  let trans={val:"fil.res=[1,2].join('&')"}
  
  console.log(`WORKS------`)
  Function('fil', '"use strict";return (' + trans.val + ')')(fil);
  console.log({fil})
  
  console.log(`FAILS-----`)
  trans={val:"fil.res=callpaul('a')"}
  Function('callpaul','fil', '"use strict";return (' + trans.val + ')')(`function callpaul (p){return 'hi'+p}`,fil);
  console.log({fil})
```

Comment: It's really not clear what exactly you want here. Why do you want to call your function "inside the scope of Function"? Why use the Function constructor instead of just creating an anonymous function? And is it supposed to return a value or store the value inside fil.res ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the Function constructor correctly - the first arguments will be the names of the parameters within the newly created argumented. I have renamed some variables to make it more understandable (the first param is the function being passed it, and the second param is where the result is stored into) and it now works.

```
console.log(`FAILS-----`) //now actually works
trans={val:"output.res=passedFunction('a')"}
//Define the new function and store it in newfunc
let newfunc = Function('passedFunction','output', '"use strict";return (' + trans.val + ')'); 
//Call the new function, passing in your callpaul function to be called, and fil to hold the result
newfunc( function callpaul (p){return 'hi'+p;}, fil) ); 
console.log({fil});
```